# Dotnet EF not recognized on multi sdk .net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 2 dotnet core sdk installed on my computer (I have 2 project, one still run on 2.2 and the other running on 3.1)
When I run dotnet ef on my project (that still using v2.2) I got this error :

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
>   framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.1' was not found.
>     - The following frameworks were found:
>         2.2.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework
>   and/or SDK.
>
> The specified framework can be found at:
>     - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.1&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

I have edit my global.json

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "2.2.8",
      "rollForward": "latestMajor"
    }
  }
```

but the error still appear everytime I need to run dotnet ef

dotnet run still okay ... it still using the correct sdk.
How to fix this ?
thank you

ps my csproj file : 
my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Client" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the [project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options) param? By default when you run the command it targets the startup project.

Comment: Can you explain more about project param? I don't think i have one

Comment: Your projects are in same solution or in individual solutions?

Comment: Individual solution. But located on the same pc.